# Converting char to Int with getchar() extra numbers

Tags: c, ascii

I want to convert a char to an int. However when I use the usual way of

```
convertedInt = c - '0';
```

I get an extra negative number when printing the results. For instance this code with the input 654 produces the output:

```
    while (c != '\n'){
        c = getchar();
        convertedInt = c - '0';
        printf("%d\n", convertedInt);
    }

    //Output
    4
    5
    6
    -38
```

I don't think it has anything to do with the getchar because if I just print the char without converting it I get the expected output.

Comment: write an if statement to not print negative numbers.

Comment: I agree that, that is a valid solution, but I don't like it. It seems sloppy. I would like to know why this happens and if I can stop it without an if statement. (How do I always know it will be -38 if I don't know why it shows up?)

Comment: it's only because your string has a few extra chars which you are not aware of!

Comment: ASCII value of newline: 10, ASCII value of 0: 48

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing before reading the character. Try this:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    convertedInt = c - '0';
    printf("%d\n", convertedInt);
}
```

Note that `getchar()` can return `EOF` in the event of an error, or if the user signals `EOF` from the keyboard, and so `c` should be tested for this value to avoid a possible infinite loop.

In the code from the question, it appears that the controlling expression of the `while` statement tests the value of `c` uninitialized the first time. This leads to undefined behavior. Later, when the last digit is read and printed, `c` is tested again and found not to be `\n`. Then `getchar()` is called and `c` has a value of `10`, the decimal value of the newline character in ASCII. So, `convertedInt` gets the value `10 - 48`, or `-38`. Then `c` is tested a final time; now it is equal to `\n`, and the loop is terminated.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `getchar` returns an `int` that normally contains a character code in the lowest byte. The reason that it returns an `int` is that it has to be able to return a value for `EOF` that is distinct from any possible `unsigned char` value. `EOF` is used to indicate the end of the input and is not meant to be treated like a character input. On  many systems, `EOF` has the value -1.

The value you are seeing is `'\n' - '0' == 10 - 48` in ASCII.

Here is a common idiom for handling the undesirable inputs from `getchar()`:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        convertedInt = c - '0';
        printf("%d\n", convertedInt); 
    }
}
```

A similar check can be acheived by including `#include <ctype.h>` and changing the condition of the `if` statement to `if(isdigit(c))`.

Comment: @DavidBowling. You are absolutely right. I am on mobile so my update took a long time to write

Comment: My keyboard doesn't let me put two spaces in a row, let's just say that

Comment: Don't know if OP needs to validate digits or not (certainly not to solve the problem in the question), but it is not a bad idea. I see that you mention the `ctype.h` functions; I just wanted to point out that in general it is better to use these than, e.g., `c >= '0' && ...`, as these functions are designed to offer a more portable solution.

Comment: @DavidBowling I'm glad you agree

Answer (score 2):

When you do `getChar()`, you are checking it for `\n` later, but you are subtracting '0' first. Replace with this

```
while(1){
    c = getchar();
    if(c == '\n')
        break;
    convertedInt = c - '0';
    printf("%d\n", convertedInt);
}
```